# Не понимаю как работает java в совокупности с js

Tags: javascript, java, spring

Занимаюсь полгода джавой и столкнулся с проблемой в веб-разработке. Начал постигать Spring boot. Из гайдов понял, что это чистый бэк-энд, но в этом и загвоздка. Зачем нужен фронт, если я через аннотацию на спринге указываю адрес к выводу информации, которую могу также обработать на джаве и не париться с фронтом? Если быть точнее, то не понимаю как работает бэк-энд и фронт в совокупности. Есть гайды по созданию приложения на спринге, есть гайды по созданию приложения на js, но как их объединить в одну структуру, чтобы все работало?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Зачем нужен фронт, если я через аннотацию на спринге указываю адрес к
> выводу информации, которую могу также обработать на джаве и не
> париться с фронтом?

Не парьтесь и с джавой тогда. Вы как с аннотациями собираетесь делать современный UI? Постоянно спрашивать у сервера всю страницу, так производительность вашего сайта будет на высоте Мариинской впадины потому что он будет всю динамику сайта просить с сервера?

> Если быть точнее, то не понимаю как работает бэкенд и фронт в
> совокупности.

Фронт отправляет запрос на бэкенд который обработав его отправляет ответ.

> Есть гайды по созданию приложения на спринге, есть гайды по созданию
> приложения на js, но как их объединить в одну структуру, чтобы все
> работало?

так вот гайдов объединенных тоже много, вам нужно остановиться с выбором и искать примеры конкретных. Потому что спринг это на бек, который обработает запрос и ответит. А вот [Vue](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/), [React](https://ru.reactjs.org/), [Angular](https://angular.io/docs) - это фронт, на забываем про [JS](https://learn.javascript.ru/) на котором всего полно.